# Validate Integer in Form Input Using is_numeric

Tags: php, mysql, post, isnumeric

In my form, a team's score is input, validated by the PHP script and then passed to the MySQL database.  However, I want to make sure that a positive integer is being submitted, so there are no problems on the back-end when league standings are tabulated.

Research led me to the conclusion that using is_numeric would be the best way to go about this.  However, it fails to recognize zero as an integer and that presents a problem for me.  When I echo it in an array by itself, it shows as true, but something about the way I've written it in the script is not working.

I tried converting the $_POST with intval first and then processing the number with is_numeric, but that doesn't seem to help.  Here's the code:

```
// Validate the away score:
if (empty($_POST['away_score'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter the away score.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['away_score'])) {
    echo "You entered an invalid score for the away team.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $away_score_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
    $validate = 'true';
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `POST[$_'$away_score']`....?   Is that just a really odd copy/paste error, or is that actually what's in your PHP script?

Comment: And why the `$` in the quotes?  You don't have it on any of the others...

Comment: @cHao Sorry, that was just me being an idiot with my copy/paste.  Fixed, but problem remains, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `'0'` is not truthy.  That means that anything that checks it in a boolean'ish manner will treat it as false.  In particular, `empty($_POST['away_score'])` will evaluate to `true`, so `is_numeric` would never even get a chance to fail.

Short version:  `empty` is too wishy-washy in this case.  Check for null and `''` explicitly.

```
if (!isset($_POST['away_score']) or $_POST['away_score'] == '') {
```

Comment: What happens when is a float like 4.2?..the op want to check a positive integer

Comment: @EmilioGort: At this point in the validation, nothing.  You'd probably want to take the `intval()` of it and see if it's loosely-equal to the input, if it has to be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use built-in validation. Explore few examples from [Validation examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php). And read about [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

For example.

```
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'score', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array(
        'min_range' => 1,
        'max_range' => 5,
    )
)));
```

P.S. use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

try {

    // Check if user submitted "away_score" with valid form.
    // "away_score" can be UNDEFINED or STRING or ARRAY.
    if (!isset($_POST['away_score']) || !is_string($away_score = $_POST['away_score'])) {
        throw new RuntimeException('You cannot access without valid form submitting.');
    }
    // If "away_score" is not filled in, this will be EMPTY STRING.
    if ($away_score === '') {
        throw new RuntimeException('You forgot to enter the away score.');
    }
    // Check if trimmed "away_score" has only digits.
    if (!ctype_digit($away_score = trim($away_score))) {
        throw new RuntimeException('You entered an invalid score for the away team.');
    }

    // do something

} catch (Exception $e) {

    printf("<p>%s</p>\n", $e->getMessage());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ctype_digit( (string) $score);

preg_match('#^\d+$#', $score);
```

In b4 @EmilioGort

```
boolean false

int 0
```

Comment: @EmilioGort it's "before" your 4.2 test ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex

```
if (preg_match('/\A\d++\z/', $variable)){//including 0
 //do somthing
}else{
 echo "This is not a Positive Integer"
}
```

`is_numeric(4.2)` return true with float

`is_int(2)` return false if the data are obtained using supergloblals like `$_POST` or `$_GET`

Comment: `/\A\d++\z/` is a perfect regex for it. `$` may contains CRLF or LF.

Comment: @CertaiN give me an example please?

Comment: http://ideone.com/fEwG6A But later `trim` he called, so this is not absolutely necessary, sorry..

Comment: And `\d++` is more efficient than `\d+`, because of no backtrack. `\d+` do backtrack on matching failure. Example: `1abcdef`; PCRE tries to check the follwing all cases. `1abcdef`->`1abcde`->`1abc`->`1ab`->`1a`->`1`

Answer (score 1):

```
} elseif (!preg_match('/^([0-9]+)$/', $_POST['away_score'], $m)) {
  $AwayScore = $m[1];  # $AwayScore to go to mysql
  echo 'not numeric!';
  $valid = false;
}
```

This just works!
preg_match() works for any type, **including integer/long/float**, anything!

Comment: why the downvote without reason....it's works, read the comments in my answer about LF and CRLF

Answer (score 0):

But using [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) *is* the proper way of checking whether a given input is or not a number in PHP, and

```
var_dump(is_numeric(0));
```

should return `bool(true)`. Have you tried [`is_int`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) instead?

Comment: 4.2 return true with is_numeric

Comment: Thanks, I did run the var_dump like you posted and it does return true.  For whatever reason, when I enter 0 into the input field, it does not recognize the number.  I will try is_int right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
elseif (!is_numeric(POST[$_'$away_score']) && !is_null(POST[$_'$away_score']))
```

Because 0 (or null) is not a numeric value, you have to check if the score isn't null.

Comment: 4.2 return true with is_numeric

Comment: `undefined` is not equal to `NULL`

Comment: NULL is equal to 0, we're not talking about undefined.

Comment: And stop talking about PDO when he is using MySQLi who is more efficiant and performant than PDO (for MySQL request).

Comment: @RobotChief Why you said that? (facts) MYSQLI > PDO

Comment: MySQLi is more fast for select request up to 2%, and creating table to  1.5%, but it's a question of optimisation, of programmer skills after all, a badly optimized code in MySQLi will be not more fast and effeciant than a PDO code.